# Allow Django Admin to change whether a field is required

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, configuration, django-forms

I'd like to be able to change whether the email field is required or not, depending on whether I'm showing a friend or a customer, without having to push to git every time and redeploy.

I have set up a Configuration model for other settings in Django which is configurable from the admin, but unfortunately I'm not able to use any of these settings in other Models or Model Fields, as it causes database errors on migration.

This is my code (it fails because of the migration issue)

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    stake = StakeField()
    email = forms.EmailField(required=getConfig(ConfigData.USER_EMAIL_REQUIRED))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

Is there another way to set the required/blank setting in either the model, modelform or form which won't cause this issue?

**Edit for clarity:**

I already have the Configuration AdminModel, but I'm struggling to use this value (True/False) in a ModelForm field without database errors, for a user facing form.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51383876/avoiding-circular-imports-in-django-models-config-class/51387007#51387007

Comment: You can construct an extra table that for every field can give you the opportunity to specify whether it is required, some sort of "*meta-table*", and then fetch from the database when constructing the field

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/jazzband/django-constance

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with just editing the formfield's required attribute?

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    stake = StakeField()
    email = forms.EmailField(required=False)

    def clean_email(self, value):
        # In case your database schema does not allow an empty value, otherwise, you can ignore this
        if not self.fields['email'].required and not value:
            # 'A friend' has used the form and the email field was not required
            value = 'whatever default/placeholder value you like'
        return value
    

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = UserForm
    
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        if not is_my_friend(request.user):
            form.base_fields['email'].required = True
        return form
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think this answers my question exactly. I already have the form in the admin site for configuration, and using the result of this configuration (`True/False`) I want to set whether the email field in a customer facing user form is required, ie. admin logs in, unchecks "require email" in admin config (already built), and the next user that signs up can leave the email field blank.

Comment: in new versions, instead of `form.fields`, use `form.base_fields`